# Symfony2: How to handle dynamic "nav" bar

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I got a nav/action bar on the left side of the document which allows me to manage data between three entities by clicking on a link.

This makes it a little complicated. There are three types of state which render:

1. Static URLs (/image/add) - Those URL's don't change and always do the same
2. Dynamic URLs (server side) - For example when I do a "showAction" I can render the slug of the showen entity into the url's
3. Dynamic URLs (client side) - For example when I do an "indexAction" I pick out an entity and jQuery sets the id of the entity into the url (/image/2383382.jpg/edit)

These three states appear sometimes together which makes it quite hard to mentain and code clearly. Also different layer get mixed up

I think there are two ways to handle this better:

1. Javascript - Only (prefered choice)
   I write a jQuery plugin which gets an JSON-Object as input and the plugin handles everything
2. Symfony Service
   A Symfony Service handles the urls and only has to get rendered by twig unfortunatly still javascript is required to select an entity without rendering edit, show actions for each entity extra

What do you think about my ideas?
Are there other/better solutions?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You always should generate urls by {{ path('route_name', { 'param1': 'value' }) }}

And for maintain routes in JS use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Comment: The JsRoutingBundle is a good idea! But this doesn't quite solve the issue how I could switch between static urls and dynamic urls. Let me make an example: When you are on an indexing site which lists all entities, than you want that the routing parameter gets set by the selected entity. But when you are on an already entity related site (edit, show, delete) this isn't required. You solve this with providing two action-bar templates (dynamic with js and static with twig variable) but this would be a doubled thing. However the main question is if I should do the action bar fully with js or not.

Comment: There is no distinction between route with parameter and without. All used routes should be rendered by router. You shouldn't do <a href="/some/static/url">static</a>, always do <a href="{{ path('some_static_url') }}">static</a> Or I maybe don't fully understand what you mean...

Comment: That is so clear that I didn't wanted to contract with ;) I mean with static routes, routes without parameter...